# PagerAdapter doesn't have the getPageWidth() method, as documented

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Using sdk version 8, with android-support-v4, I am trying to make implement a PagerAdapter that shows multiple pages at once.

Found some good advice online, that indicated the best way to achieve this is to override the getPageWidth(int) method on PagerAdapter.

http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

However, PagerAdapter does not have that method in the android-support-v4.jar. I can't figure out why, since androids own documentation does confirm the existence of that method.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth%28int%29)

The problem of course if that if the method doesn't exist, it makes no sense to override it as it would never be called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JAR is out of date, presumably. Make sure that you are on the latest Android Support package. Or, grab the JAR from [the sample project that I linked to in the blog post](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1).

Comment: Do not forget add same library to other referenced libraries! Like me:D